# Lasers: The Reflection (Level 2)

Tags: visual, grid-deduction, optimization

Previous Level:- [Lasers : Introduction (Level $1$)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104587/lasers-introduction-level-1)

So here is my lasers level 2 continued, and I have something new, mirrors!

**Rules**:

- There will be lasers which are shaped like an arrow. The arrows pointing in the respective direction shows where the laser goes and the colour shows the colour which it gives out.
- There will be boxes which are respectively coloured and these boxes need to get touched by the lasers in order to find a solution.
- The solution however, will not be given as usual. In order to find the solution, you can make a move by rotating the lasers 90° clockwise.
- Each box should receive the light of one single laser. In future levels a box may receive the light of 2 or more lasers.
- Lasers(the arrows of the lasers) and Grey Tiles, along with the sides of the Mirrors would block other lasers' paths. Here is an example where a laser blocks another laser's path.

[image]

**What's New** :-

- From now, we will have mirrors in our grid. A mirror reflects a laser's path in exactly 90° angle clockwise or counter-clockwise, depending on the path. A mirror would only reflect the laser it is facing, or else it will block other laser paths. 2 examples are given here :-
  [image]
- There will be grey tiles from now. They will block the paths of lasers completely.
- From now, there will be more than 1 colour. Every box of a specific colour should get a laser of that colour, it should not get a laser of a different colour.
- You can also rotate a mirror 90° clockwise, in that case it will be considered as a move.
- You may/may not use all the mirrors in the grid in order to find a solution.

Here is the real puzzle, can you solve it? (Level 2)

I can also confirm this is unique.

[image]

**Bonus** :- Can you count the number of moves it takes to go the the solution? (Moves include either rotating a laser or a mirror 90° clockwise.)

I will give the checkmark to the one who solves both the parts the first, along with explanation.

Comment: You say "Lasers block other lasers' paths". Does it mean that two lasers' paths cannot intersect? It does not seem solvable with that constraint, because rot13(gur erq evtugzbfg neebj vf vfbyngrq ol gur terra ynfre cngu).

Comment: No, the lights may intersect. I will give a picture for the understanding.

Comment: Cool game! Interestingly I was going to post a very similar puzzle. If you are going to make an app out of this then I suggest checking some similar games: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pyrosphere.lazors&hl=en https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tapanywhere.laseroverload&hl=en&gl=US

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky well I didn't think of making apps though, as I am not a programmer, but it would have been great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Total Moves: 45

Where row, column, number of moves:

Moves needed for laser 2 (from left to right top to bottom).

> 4,7,1

> 3,7,3

> 3,5,3

> 1,1,2

Moves needed for red laser 1:

> 4,1,3

Moves needed for blue laser 2:

> 5,3,2

> 5,5,3

> 7,5,2

Moves needed for blue laser 1:

> 3,4,2

> 2,4,3

> 2,7,3

Moves needed for Green laser 1:

> 1,6,1

> 6,6,3

> 6,7,2

Finally for Green laser 2:

> 6,4,3

> 6,3,3

> 7,3,3

> 7,1,2

> 5,1,1

Picture:

[image]

Explanation:

> The yellow line represents the path the laser has to travel from the lazer to the box. The rotations required can be explained above.

Comment: Whoa I am not a computer, can you give a picture of the solution? I can just read the solution though.

Comment: Sorry I am not an artist, I did this all on my phone, so drawing it will take ages.

Comment: Ok, can you explain the logic on how you got solution? Maybe it will be better then.

Comment: actually I got an idea give me a sec.

Comment: Better now??????

Comment: Cool, it's better. I will be waiting for you to explain the logic :). (A small mistake is there in R1C2 and R2C2 if you spot it.)

Comment: Sorry is there more than one solution?

Comment: Are you getting another one, because this is unique.

Comment: Any clearer now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115916/discussion-between-anonymous-and-prince-deepthinker).