# Lasers: Cross through the bridges (Level 3)

Tags: visual, grid-deduction, optimization

Previous Level:- [Lasers: The Reflection (Level 2)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104592/lasers-the-reflection-level-2)

**Rules** :

- There will be lasers which are shaped like an arrow. The arrows pointing in the respective direction shows where the laser goes and the colour shows the colour which it gives out.
- There will be boxes which are respectively coloured and these boxes need to get touched by the lasers in order to find a solution.
- A mirror reflects a laser's path in exactly 90° angle clockwise or counter-clockwise, depending on the path. A mirror would only reflect the laser it is facing, or else it will block other laser paths.
- The solution however, will not be given as usual. In order to find the solution, you can make a move by rotating the lasers or the mirrors 90° clockwise.
- Each box should receive the light of one single laser. In future levels a box may receive the light of 2 or more lasers.
- Lasers(the arrows of the lasers) and Grey Tiles, along with the sides of the Mirrors would block other lasers' paths. Here is an example where a laser blocks another laser's path.

**What's New** :-

- From now on, we will have Bridges in our grid. Bridges allow lasers to only cross through a box from a particular direction, it would block lasers coming from other directions. Bridges also have the colour which shows the colour from a which a laser can pass through, any other coloured lasers cannot pass through it. Examples are given below :-

[image]

- You may/may not use all the bridges present in the grid to find a solution. However, for this level, the red laser must pass through each bridge.
- Bridges cannot be rotated in this case. However, in future levels, they may be rotated.

Here is the real puzzle for  today. Can you solve it? (Level 3)

[image]

**Bonus** :- Find the number of moves it takes to find the solution (moves include either rotating a laser or a mirror 90° clockwise.)

Comment: This is not [tag:grid-deduction] unless there is a unique answer, findable through logical deduction alone. It also appears to be very low effort -- it's easy to make these "optimization puzzles" just by throwing some pieces down and rotating them arbitrarily.

Comment: I am sorry sir, but there is a UNIQUE answer, findable through logical deduction alone. I also don't think you would consider this as a low effort by the rotation of the pieces, rather considering on how to use them to get the solution.

Comment: These are really fun by the way, I am looking foward to more challenging ones... How many have you made may I ask...?

Comment: I will make more as time goes :) .

Comment: @Anonymous It seems like the answer was *not* unique. You should ensure that your [grid-deduction] puzzles have a *purely logically deductive solve path*. That is, *every single thing in the answer* should be possible to figure out with 100% confidence, by ruling out all other possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little explaination:

> The blue line drawn represents the lasers path from the start to the square. Also the laser rotates once to start... A rule I saw was that the laser could not move in the same direction for 3 squares at once if it encountered 3 mirrors at once.

[image]

Comment: Do you also want me to explain the rotations?

Comment: No not needed, can you explain the logic?

Comment: (Actually it wasn't unique before, sorry for the inconvenience :3, I have made it better now) .

Comment: Huh what do you mean?

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: In R5C7 I have changed it to a grey tile, or else there would have been $2$ ways for the blue line.

Comment: My solution still fits.

Comment: No, or else you would have done R6C6 to R5C6 to R5C7 as the path of the blue line.

Comment: It still works, I did not use that square?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115935/discussion-between-anonymous-and-prince-deepthinker).