# Lasers: (Rotation + Movement) (Level 4)

Tags: visual, optimization, sliding-blocks

Previous Level: [Lasers: Cross through the bridges (Level 3)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104612/lasers-cross-through-the-bridges-level-3)

Here's another level for my new puzzle, after a long time. Some new ideas came too:

**Rules**:

- There will be lasers which are shaped like an arrow. The arrows pointing in the respective direction shows where the laser goes and the colour shows the colour which it gives out.
- There will be boxes which are respectively coloured and these boxes need to get touched by the lasers in order to find a solution. In order to find the solution, you can make a move by rotating the lasers or the mirrors 90° clockwise.
- A mirror reflects a laser's path in exactly 90° angle clockwise or counter-clockwise, depending on the path. A mirror would only reflect the laser it is facing, or else it will block other laser paths.
- Each box should receive the light of one single laser. In future levels a box may receive the light of 2 or more lasers.
- Lasers(the arrows of the lasers) and Grey Tiles, along with the sides of the Mirrors would block other lasers' paths.
- Bridges have a specific colour allow lasers to cross through a box from a particular direction from the same colour, or else it would block lasers from coming through other directions as well as lasers with different colours. Bridges cannot be rotated but in future levels they may be rotated.

**What's New**:

From now, you can not only rotate lasers, mirrors, etc.; but can also move them side to side. You can also move grey tiles, only brown tiles can neither be moved nor rotated.

In one move, you can move 1 object (like lasers, mirrors, grey-tiles, bridges, etc.) such that they move as far as possible in the grid in a particular direction, until they reach the edge, or they collide with another piece.

[image]

After understanding the movement pattern, here is the real puzzle for today. Can you solve it? (Level 4) .

[image]

**Note** :- If you understood the rules, then this level is going to be far more easy than previous ones. But more levels will be coming soon :) .

Comment: Can you move the grey square even though it does not end on the corner but just to the other side?

Comment: Yes, you can. Only the brown tiles cannot be moved nor rotated. From now you can move grey squares.

Comment: Can you move the grey tiles into the red tiles?

Comment: You can move the tiles such that they reach the other side, or they stop by touching another tile.

Comment: I mean can they over lap?

Comment: Nope, they can't.

Comment: But can the laser overlap with the red tile

Comment: But can the laser overlap with the red tile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116083/discussion-between-anonymous-and-prince-deepthinker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so:

Step 1:

> R2C2 3 Down

2. 

> R1C5 3 left and 3 down

3. 

> R3C6 4 left

4. 

> R6C4 3 up

5. 

> R2C6 1 down and 1 left

6. 

> R3C4 1 down

7. 

> R4C6 1 left

8. 

> R4C4 1 down

9. 

> R5C6 1 left

10. 

> R2C4 2 down

Final Positions:

[image]

Comment: How about a picture of the final position?

Comment: Ok sure I will try...

Comment: Is this better now?

Comment: Just to add, I hope you continue this and maybe make more challenging ones.