# Lasers: Everything is Switched (Level 5)

Tags: visual, sliding-blocks

Previous Level: [Lasers: (Rotation + Movement) (Level 4)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104725/lasers-rotation-movement-level-4)

Here is another level, this is a bit tough I guess, but enjoy solving using the previous rules!

**Rules** :

- There will be lasers that are shaped like an arrow. The arrows pointing in the respective direction shows where the laser goes and the colour shows the colour which it gives out.
- There will be boxes that are respectively coloured and these boxes need to get touched by the lasers to find a solution. To find the solution, you can make a move by rotating or moving the lasers or the mirrors, or moving the grey tiles or the coloured boxes 90° clockwise.
- A mirror reflects a laser's path in exactly 90° angle clockwise or counter-clockwise, depending on the path. A mirror would only reflect the laser it is facing, or else it will block other laser paths.
- Each box should receive the light of one single laser. In future levels, a box may receive the light of 2 or more lasers.
- Lasers (the arrows of the lasers) and Grey Tiles, along with the sides of the Mirrors would block other lasers' paths.
- Bridges have a specific colour to allow lasers to cross through a box from a particular direction from the same colour, or else it would block lasers from coming through other directions as well as lasers with different colours. Bridges cannot be rotated but in future levels, they may be rotated.
- You can move objects (like lasers, mirrors, grey-tiles, bridges, etc.) such that they move as far as possible in the grid in a particular direction, until they reach the edge, or they collide with another piece. Brown objects cannot be moved.

Here is another puzzle, can you solve it? (Level 5)

[image]

**Note**: It has been already mentioned in the rules you can move coloured boxes unless they are surrounded by brown lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer seems to ignore the rule that a block moves as far as possible when moving and the other one is a bit much to scroll through, have a 37-move diagram:

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

It looks like

> If we were to shuffle the boxes around the outside, almost everything is in the right order except the red and blue on the right which need to be switched and we can use the gap on the left hand side to do that.

So let's do this first

> Move all the boxes around the outside clockwise until the red box that was originally on the right ends up in the middle on the left and we get the following configuration.
>  [image]

Now switch red and blue with the following moves

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

And move everything back

> By moving all the coloured blocks counter-clockwise around the outside of the square, we can get to the following configuration
>  [image]

Comment: Nice, you got it.

Comment: I worked out another solution may I post it op?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope this is clear enough for you to follow!

Comment: Nice, you got it as well.