# Lasers: Moving Mirrors (Level 7)

Tags: visual, sliding-blocks

Previous Level:- [Lasers: Doubled Bridges (Level 6)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104763/lasers-doubled-bridges-level-6)

Here is another level for the game. I have added nothing new, but the level can be a bit tricky this time.

**Rules** :

- There will be lasers which are shaped like an arrow. The arrows pointing in the respective direction shows where the laser goes and the colour shows the colour which it gives out.
- There will be boxes which are respectively coloured and these boxes need to get touched by the lasers in order to find a solution. In order to find the solution, you can make a move by rotating or moving the lasers or the mirrors, or moving the grey tiles or the coloured boxes 90° clockwise.
- A mirror reflects a laser's path in exactly 90° angle clockwise or counter-clockwise, depending on the path. A mirror would only reflect the laser it is facing, or else it will block other laser paths.
- Each box should receive the light of one single laser. In future levels a box may receive the light of 2 or more lasers.
- Lasers(the arrows of the lasers) and Grey Tiles, along with the sides of the Mirrors would block other lasers' paths.
- (Bridges)/(Doubled-Bridges) have a specific colour to allow lasers to cross through a box from a particular direction from the same colour, or else it would block lasers from coming through other directions as well as lasers with different colours. Bridges cannot be rotated but in future levels they may be rotated.
- Brown tiles (or tiles surrounded by brown lines) can neither be rotated nor be moved, they will be static.
- You can move objects (like lasers, mirrors, grey-tiles, bridges, etc.) such that they move as far as possible in the grid in a particular direction, until they reach the edge, or they collide with another piece. Brown objects cannot be moved.

Here is the puzzle for today, can you solve it? (Level 7)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this final configuration would work

> [image]

How do you get this configuration

> From now on, I will refer to the central $6 \times 6$ grid in terms of rows and columns. The original positions of the mirrors are R6C1, R6C2, R6C3, R6C4, R6C5 and R6C6. Firstly, move the mirror at R6C5 straight up. Then move the R6C4 mirror right and then up, then the R6C3 right and up, then the R6C2, then R6C1, until you end up with the following configuration
>  [image]
>  Now move the mirror at R4C5 to the left. Move the mirror at R3C5 down and the left, then R2C5 down and then left and finally, R1C5 down and then left until you end up with the following
>  [image]
>  You will start to notice the pattern now. Move the mirror at R4C3 up, then the mirror at R4C2 right and up and then the mirror at R4C1 right and up until you get the following
>  [image]
>  Now move the mirror at R2C3 left and then move the mirror at R1C3 down and left to get the following
>  [image]
>  Move the mirror at R2C1 straight up to finish.

Comment: @Anonymous Are you saying that all pieces move as far as possible until they collide with something? This isn't stated in the original question - you may want to edit that in.

Comment: @Anonymous Ah, okay I didn't get that from the original rules

Comment: @hexomino that's correct, you got it !

Answer (score 0):

A modification of @hexomino's answer, which drops six moves:

> Split the problem in two: Move r6c3/5/6 upwards, then move r6c1/2 right and up and r1c5/6 left and down.
>  Move r2c3 left, r1c3 down and left, r5c4 right, r6c4 up and right, then finally r2c1 up and r5c6 down.