# Lasers: Double-Sided Mirrors (Level 8)

Tags: visual, sliding-blocks

Previous Level:- [Lasers: Moving Mirrors (Level 7)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104792/lasers-moving-mirrors-level-7)

Here is another level of the continuation of my game. I have some doubled mirrors as a gift!

**Rules** :

- There will be lasers that are shaped like an arrow. The arrows pointing in the respective direction shows where the laser goes and the colour shows the colour which it gives out.
- There will be boxes that are respectively coloured and these boxes need to get touched by the lasers in order to find a solution. In order to find the solution, you can make a move by rotating or moving the lasers or the mirrors, or moving the grey tiles or the coloured boxes 90° clockwise.
- A mirror reflects a laser's path in exactly 90° angle clockwise or counter-clockwise, depending on the path. A mirror would only reflect the laser it is facing, or else it will block other laser paths.
- Each box should receive the light of one single laser. In future levels, a box may receive the light of 2 or more lasers.
- Lasers (the arrows of the lasers) and Grey Tiles, along with the sides of the Mirrors would block other lasers' paths.
- (Bridges)/(Doubled-Bridges) have a specific colour to allow lasers to cross through a box from a particular direction from the same colour, or else it would block lasers from coming through other directions as well as lasers with different colours. Bridges cannot be rotated but in future levels, they may be rotated.
- Brown tiles (or tiles surrounded by brown lines) can neither be rotated nor be moved, they will be static.
- You can move objects (like lasers, mirrors, grey-tiles, bridges, etc.) such that they move as far as possible in the grid in a particular direction until they reach the edge, or they collide with another piece. Brown objects cannot be moved.

**What's New**:-

- From now on, we will have double-sided mirrors. They work exactly like a mirror does, but reflects 2 lasers together in 2 particular directions. Brown-coloured double-sided mirrors can neither be moved nor rotated.

[image]

Here is the real puzzle for today. Can you solve it? (Level 8)

[image]

**Note**:- If you are liking this game (or this series of puzzles), I think a bit of more feedback will be better for me. Please give some feedback on this puzzle series and some suggestions.

Comment: Can we rotate these mirrors?

Comment: Yes, non-brown coloured objects can be both rotated and moved. However, $2$ rotations of the same mirror will make it come to the same configuration, as they move $90^\circ$ each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little bit of re-configuration and rotations, I found this works.

Explanation:

The brown lines represent mirrors and the blue, red, yellow, and green lines represent the lasers.

> [image]

Steps:

1.

> Rotate all mirrors 90 degrees clockwise.

2. 

> R2C3 - 1 left and 3 down

3. 

> R2C4 - 2 Left

4. 

> R4C5 - 1 down

5. 

> R4C4 - 1 down

6. 

> R3C4 - 1 down

7. 

> R5C4 - 1 left

Comment: How did you reach to that position for example?

Comment: You want me to give the movements in RnCn?

Comment: Yeah, I think it will be better for me to see if you are correct in your approach or not.

Comment: I have been able to solve all the puzzles thus far but the sixth one is too hard to do on my phone. They are getting more challenging, I especially liked solving number 7!

Comment: I had a different approach to hexomino.

Comment: You can post your approach if you want, it will be good if you do it!

Comment: I don't think it will get me much reputation so I am not willing.

Comment: I might give you a +1 if you want :-I . It's always better to post your answer if you want it to. It might give you reputation as well as the question will go to the top.

Answer (score 2):

> Other solution (which does not use the two corner mirrors):
> `/ /`
> `/ /`
>     `/ /`
>     `/ /`

Comment: Great, that seems to be even more simpler.