# Lasers: An Easy Puzzle (Level 9)

Tags: visual, sliding-blocks

Previous Level:- [Lasers: Double-Sided Mirrors (Level $8$)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104822/lasers-double-sided-mirrors-level-8)

**Rules** :

- There will be lasers that are shaped like an arrow. The arrows pointing in the respective direction shows where the laser goes and the colour shows the colour which it gives out.
- There will be boxes that are respectively coloured and these boxes need to get touched by the lasers in order to find a solution. In order to find the solution, you can make a move by rotating or moving the lasers or the mirrors, or moving the grey tiles or the coloured boxes 90° clockwise.
- A mirror reflects a laser's path in exactly 90° angle clockwise or counter-clockwise, depending on the path. Double-sided mirrors can reflect 2 laser paths in 2 particular directions.
- Each box should receive the light of one single laser. In future levels, a box may receive the light of 2 or more lasers.
- Lasers(the arrows of the lasers) and Grey Tiles, along with the sides of the Mirrors would block other lasers' paths.
- (Bridges)/(Doubled-Bridges) have a specific colour to allow lasers to cross through a box from a particular direction from the same colour, or else it would block lasers from coming through other directions as well as lasers with different colours. Bridges cannot be rotated but in future levels, they may be rotated.
- Brown tiles (or tiles surrounded by brown lines) can neither be rotated nor be moved, they will be static.
- You can move objects (like lasers, mirrors, grey-tiles, bridges, etc.) such that they move as far as possible in the grid in a particular direction until they reach the edge, or they collide with another piece. Brown objects cannot be moved.

**What's New**:-

- Blue Lines are transparent, that is, they allow other pieces to move through them, but blocks lasers' paths. Typically they work like grey\brown tiles but allows the movement of the pieces.

Here is the puzzle for today, can you solve it? (Level 9)

[image: the puzzle]

Comment: Just got on, are you sure that there is no mistake here... it seems too obvious.

Comment: Indeed trivial, unless the 'all mirrors must be used' rule is intended. Then it is a more interesting puzzle (i.m.o.). Rotate one laser and ask for the longest path, and the solution is unique (always a good thing). However that is a way different puzzle than intended I guess.

Comment: I hope this is more clear, sorry for those mistakes (I missed to give $2$ more blue lines, also I edited it a bit) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Brown lines represents the mirrors, the blue and green lines represents the laser's path

> [image]

Moves:

> R2C5 left, R5C2 up, R1C4 down and right, R1C5 down, left and down, R5C1 right and up, R4C1 down.

Comment: How did you get to that configuration? Let me know.

Comment: Better now?????

Comment: Better, nice work.