# Lasers: Colour-Converters (Level 10)

Tags: visual, sliding-blocks

Previous Level:- [Lasers: An Easy Puzzle (Level $9$)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104848/lasers-an-easy-puzzle-level-9)

**Rules** :

Welcome to the 10th level of my puzzle series, and now we have colour converters!

- There will be lasers that are shaped like an arrow. The arrows pointing in the respective direction shows where the laser goes and the colour shows the colour which it gives out.
- There will be boxes that are respectively coloured and these boxes need to get touched by the lasers in order to find a solution. In order to find the solution, you can make a move by rotating or moving the lasers or the mirrors, or moving the grey tiles or the coloured boxes 90° clockwise.
- A mirror reflects a laser's path in exactly 90° angle clockwise or counter-clockwise, depending on the path. Double-sided mirrors can reflect 2 laser paths in 2 particular directions.
- Each box should receive the light of one single laser. In future levels, a box may receive the light of 2 or more lasers.
- Lasers(the arrows of the lasers) and Grey Tiles, along with the sides of the Mirrors would block other lasers' paths.
- (Bridges)/(Doubled-Bridges) have a specific colour to allow lasers to cross through a box from a particular direction from the same colour, or else it would block lasers from coming through other directions as well as lasers with different colours. Bridges cannot be rotated but in future levels, they may be rotated.
- Brown tiles (or tiles surrounded by brown lines) can neither be rotated nor be moved, they will be static.
- You can move objects (like lasers, mirrors, grey-tiles, bridges, etc.) such that they move as far as possible in the grid in a particular direction until they reach the edge, or they collide with another piece. Brown objects cannot be moved.
- Blue lines allow the movement of all pieces, but blocks lasers' paths, typically the same thing what a grey/brown tile does.

**What's New**:-

- From now on, we will have colour-converters. They change the colour of the laser passing through it, into another laser colour. Different laser colours cannot be converted by a specific colour-converter, instead they will get blocked. Colour-Converters can be rotated 90° clockwise . Here are some examples :-

[image]

Here is the puzzle for today, can you solve it? (Level 10)

[image]

Comment: This seems like it's not all too difficult to actually *solve*, just tedious to get things into the correct order. I worry that a lot of these questions don't actually have specific 'aha moments' you need, so the major barrier to solvability is the lack of interactivity -- which doesn't make for an enjoyable puzzle.

Comment: I think that you, as a moderator, should talk about the improvements on this types of puzzles (for example, how to make these more challenging, how to add more ideas,etc.) rather than pointing out the mistakes and claiming it to be low-quality. If you have solved it, then you can share your answer with us. If not, please let others solve it. I also think that your opinion is not enough to decide that this puzzle is enjoyable or not.

Comment: As with your past puzzles, seeing *how to solve it* is pretty simple: you can use the notch to remove and insert things from the cycle however you want. So the red-blue converter and the blue block should be put in between mirrors 4 and 5, and then you're done. But writing out the actual steps, step-by-step, would take an annoyingly long time.

Comment: If you want to make a high-quality puzzle like this, I'd recommend making it *less tedious to write out the solution to*. Right now, even if you get all the 'aha moments' necessary, it still takes forever to actually write out a solution, which makes the puzzle significantly less fun to solve. As for design, instead of adding more and more components, focus on arranging things to give a single "logical chokepoint" that *must* be figured out to solve your puzzle. Adding more components makes the rules more complex, but doesn't actually make the puzzles harder.

Comment: (Also, the MathJax in your title and post doesn't do anything but make the puzzle more inaccessible for screenreaders. Please don't use MathJax just for basic formatting - it should only be used for equations, or complicated formatting that absolutely needs it (such as a table).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1

> There seem to be a few different ways to do this but here is one possibility.
>  Firstly, shuffle the mirrors in the upper right corner anti-clockwise one step. Then shuffle the red-green converter, the green block and the blue block anti-clockwise and the red-blue converter out of the notch and anti-clockwise. Finally, the yellow block moves right as far as it goes and the red-yellow converter moves anti-clockwise and into the notch. At this point the configuration looks like this.
>  [image]

Step 2

> Leaving the red-yellow converter where it is, shuffle everything else anti-clockwise around the outside until the first three mirrors pass the notch with said converter, to get to the following
>  [image]

Step 3

> Move the red-yellow converter down and clockwise. Then move the three adjacent mirrors clockwise along with the yellow block and move the yellow block up into the notch. Then move the same three mirrors anti-clockwise again past the notch. After all this, we get something that looks as follows
>  [image]

Step 4

> Move the yellow block down and anticlockwise. Move the three mirrors clockwise past the notch. Move the red-blue converter clockwise and into the notch and move one of the three mirrors anti-clockwise again so that the configuration looks like this. This movement requires moving each of the other pieces one space clockwise to accommodate the move.
>  [image]

Step 5

> Move the red-blue converter down and clockwise. Move the mirror in the bottom right clockwise. Then move every piece one space clockwise so this mirror just passes the notch. Move the blue square clockwise and up into the notch and the move the mirror back anti-clockwise. We then have the following configuration.
>  [image]

Step 6

> Move the blue square down a place, we have everything in the right order. Now we can move everything around clockwise until we get the following configuration.
>  [image]

Step 7

> Finally just rotate the red-yellow converter 90 degrees clockwise and we are done.
>  [image]